# Wordpress retain formatting when calling extended content?

Tags: php, wordpress, formatting, strip

I am calling in content in Wordpress via the below code. Eseentially, I am dividing the content of the post into three sections; 1. Before the  tag, 2. After the  tag and 3. Post gallery. The code I have so far works perfectly to get the content, however I am having an issue as all formatting tags (p in particular) are being stripped. Is there a way to retain these?

Thanks

```
<?php 
// Fetch post content
$content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() );
// Get content parts
$content_parts = get_extended( $content );
?>
<p>
<?php echo $content_parts['main']; // Output content before <!--more--> ?>  
</p>
<p class="read-more">
<?php echo strip_shortcodes($content_parts['extended']); // Output content after <!--more--> ?> 
</p>
<button>Read More</button>
<?php $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post ); ?>
```

Comment: Is it all of the HTML or just the paragraph tags? When you pull the content using get_post_field, the filter that adds paragraphs is not applied. Does it work when you call get_extended with get_the_content? `$content_parts = get_extended( get_the_content() );`

Comment: It appears to be all html that it is stripping. Would you mind placing the code you have supplied in the relevent position, as i used it in place of the below and it didn't work?
    $content_parts = get_extended( $content );

Comment: Sorry, no it seems to retain formatting that is manually entered in the html editor. For example <em> is retained. However, obviously I don't want to manually input <p> tags throughout the site?

Comment: See my answer. I was mistaken about get_the_content, the content filters are not applied automatically when calling that function. They are when calling the_content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pull the post content using get_post_field, the autop filter is not applied:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

You can apply all of the content filters yourself by adding this line after you set `$content`:

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I'm getting an empty <p> tag at the beginning of the main content, apart from that it is spot on. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is you have some extra lines at the top of your post. You can try removing them in the editor, or call trim on $content before applying the filter: `$content = apply_filters('the_content', trim($content));`

Comment: There are no spaces at all above the content in the CMS, which is frustrating. The trim doesn't seem to work either, or perhaps I'm not understanding your intended positioning? How is this supposed to trim the first <p>? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Autop will convert line breaks to paragraphs. Trim should remove any extra lines from the beginning and end of the content, before the filter is applied. If that isn't working then I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Just to clarify on the above answer, there does seem to be a significant bug. Without the above code, no formatting filters are passed to the output, however with this code there are two random <p> tags inserted above and below the [main] section of text. There seems no way to bypass these and they are definitely not accidental formatting in the backend, as this is 100% clean. The odd thing is these <p> tags actually contain a series of spaces, thus meaning they are not strictly 'empty'?